# Compare all columns of a table to the same 'reference' column to see if any of them differ from the reference

Tags: r, compare, multiple-columns

I'm relatively new to R and cannot figure out how to do this. Here's a link to something similar i think:

[R - Comparing values in a column and creating a new column with the results of this comparison. Is there a better way than looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794006/r-comparing-values-in-a-column-and-creating-a-new-column-with-the-results-of-t)

[How can I compare a value in a column to the previous one using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225038/how-can-i-compare-a-value-in-a-column-to-the-previous-one-using-r)

[comparing the columns and finding the values unique to a column using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256102/comparing-the-columns-and-finding-the-values-unique-to-a-column-using-r?rq=1)

```
    Row     G1        M1        M2        M3            CompareColumn
    1        2         2         2         2                None
    2        1         2         2         2                G1
    3        1         2         2         2                G1
    4        1         3         3         3                G1
    5        3         2         1         3                G1, M1
    6        3         1         1         1                G1
    7        2         2         2         2                None
    8        2         2         2         2                None
    9        1         2         3         1                G1, M2
    10       2         2         3         2                M2
```

I want to compare the values of G1, M1 and M2 to M3. If any of them are different than M3, then in the CompareColumn, print the names of the columns that are different.

Here's some pseudo-code that may help:

```
 for each column in row 
 {
   if value in column != M3
     {
     df$CompareColumn = column.name
##when there's already a name, add ", " + column.name
     }

   else 
     {
     df$CompareColumn = None
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate the idea literally into code, this might help:

```
a$CompareColumn <- apply(a[, 2:4] != a[, 5], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x), paste(colnames(a)[2:4][x], collapse=', '), 'None'))
```

There must be some better solutions, though.